# gatsby-image-background using v3 gatsby-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am trying to make gatsby-background-image work with v3 of gatsby-plugin-image. I have followed documentation and found I should be using gbimage-bridge.

For some reason it doesn't seem to work. My query works fine when testing in ide. I have tried to change my query and consts in all sorts of ways but can't seem to make it work.

Right now it just outputs the text Test but no background is being displayed.

My code:

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import { getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import { BgImage } from "gbimage-bridge"

const GbiBridged = () => {
  const { backgroundImage123 } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      backgroundImage123: allWpPage {
        nodes {
          ACFforside {
            heroimg {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  gatsbyImageData(
                    width: 2000
                    quality: 50
                    placeholder: BLURRED
                    formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                  )
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const pluginImage = getImage(backgroundImage123)

  return (
        <BgImage image={pluginImage}>Test</BgImage>
  )
}

export default GbiBridged
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your snippet should look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import { getImage, GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

import { convertToBgImage } from "gbimage-bridge"
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'

const GbiBridged = () => {
  const { backgroundImage123 } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        backgroundImage123: allWpPage {
          nodes {
           ACFforside {
             heroimg {
               localFile {
                 childImageSharp {
                   gatsbyImageData(
                     width: 2000
                     quality: 50
                     placeholder: BLURRED
                     formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                   )
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
    `
  )
  const image = getImage(backgroundImage123.nodes[0].ACFforside.heroimg.localFile)

  // Use like this:
  const bgImage = convertToBgImage(image)

  return (
    <BackgroundImage
      Tag="section"
      // Spread bgImage into BackgroundImage:
      {...bgImage}
      preserveStackingContext
    >
      <div style={{minHeight: 1000, minWidth: 1000}}>
        <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={"testimage"}/>
      </div>
    </BackgroundImage>
  )
}
export default GbiBridged
```

I'm assuming that your query is fetching the right nodes, otherwise, test it in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground

Comment: Thanks, Ferran! Now page just turns blank and gives console error: "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `image` is marked as required in `GatsbyImage`, but its value is `undefined`"..... I have checked ___graphql playground and my query seems to be fetching the right nodes. Screenshot: https://p221.p4.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/NQuwmBXP/72998327-63ca-4c89-b433-3daaa63cdca0.png?v=4f1b1842ce6368d8c42b520254d6c802

Comment: I was missing this:       `const image = getImage(backgroundImage123.nodes[0].ACFforside.heroimg.localFile)` If this doesn't work (because I typed the structure fast) check that you are passing the right node to the `getImage` function